# Get ID from a table

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table of data from mysql to php

```
echo"<table id='tableedit'>"

echo"<tr>";
echo"<td class='get'>";
echo $id;
echo $title;
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";

echo"<tr>";
echo"<td class='comments'>";
echo $comments;
echo"</tr>";
echo"</td>";
```

So the information looks like:

```
ID:1
Title:something
Comments:something..
```

And there are more as the user inputs them. I am trying to enable the user to edit their comments using an inline edit:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


    $('#tableedit tr td.comments').click(function () {
     var html = $(this).text();
     var input = $('<input type="text"; />');
    input.val(html);
               $(this).replaceWith(input);
                          $('#tableedit input').focus();
                            $('#tableedit input').blur(function () {

                              var review =(this.value);
               $(this).replaceWith(review);                                   
             //$.post('editcomments.php',{review:review});

            });                              
       });
  });
```

The inline text edit is working fine but the problem is i want to post the comments to mysql data via `ajax`however i want to get the `$id`value of each comments from the table. I have tried this which gives me a null value

```
    var id = $(this).(html).parent('#tableedit').find('tr td #get');
alert(id);  //gives a null value
```

Any advice?

Comment: there are several simpler ways to output html from php without writing `echo` on every line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the `id` as an attribute:

```
echo "<td data-id='$id' class='comments'>";
```

and then you could easily retrieve it with:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```